# Polyline overlay is not showing up on MapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, overlay, polyline

I'm currently building an Uber clone with Swift and Firebase, following Stephan Dowless' [course on Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/programmatic-uber-clone-swift-firebase-no-storyboards/) to learn more about MapKit, and so far it's going well, but I'm struggling to add a polyline overlay to the map, showing the route from the user's current location to the annotation (which is added to the mapView by tapping one of the search results displayed in a tableView).

I've looked for other similar questions on SO but haven't found anything that answers my question. I've also tried cloning other projects that use this feature ([the completed Uber clone from the Udemy course](https://github.com/sdowless/UberTutorial), [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9956648-mapkit-tutorial-overlay-views) and [this article on polylines using SwiftUI](https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-tutorial-finding-a-route-and-directions-52b973530f8d)) to check whether it's my code that's the problem but they all present the same problem i.e. the annotations appear on the screen but the overlay doesn't appear at all.

In my app, tapping "Starbucks" on the tableView in [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddtEJ.png) produces [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxws4.jpg) (showing the annotation for Starbucks and user's current location, but no overlay).

Similarly, running the [SwiftUI MapKit tutorial app from Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-tutorial-finding-a-route-and-directions-52b973530f8d) mentioned previously shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SKOe.jpg) (both annotations but no overlay).

This leads me to believe that it's something wrong on my side. I've also tried running these apps on my phone (iPhone 7) with the same issues.

Here are the relevant lines of code:

**Declaration of properties including route and mapView**

```
// MARK:- Properties
    
    private let mapView = MKMapView()
    private var searchResults = [MKPlacemark]()
    private var route: MKRoute?
```

**mapView delegate set to self (function called when user is confirmed to be logged in)**

```
private func configureMapView() {
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.frame = view.frame
        
        mapView.delegate = self
        
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
    }
```

**MapView Functions**

```
// MARK:- MapView Functions

extension HomeViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    
    private func generatePolyline(toDestination destination: MKMapItem) {
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()
        request.destination = destination
        request.transportType = .automobile
        
        let directionRequest = MKDirections(request: request)
        directionRequest.calculate { (response, error) in
            guard let response = response else { return }
            self.route = response.routes[0]
            guard let polyline = self.route?.polyline else { return }
            self.mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
            
        }
    }
    
    private func searchBy(naturalLanguageQuery: String, completion: @escaping([MKPlacemark]) -> Void) {
        var results = [MKPlacemark]()
        
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.region = mapView.region
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = naturalLanguageQuery
        
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { (response, error) in
            guard let response = response else { return }
            
            response.mapItems.forEach { (item) in
                results.append(item.placemark)
            }
            completion(results)
        }
        
    }
    
    // Change driver annotation appearance to Uber arrow
    public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if let annotation = annotation as? DriverAnnotation {
            let view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: DriverAnnotation.identifier)
            view.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chevron-sign-to-right")
            return view
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if let route = self.route {
            let polyline = route.polyline
            let lineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: polyline)
            lineRenderer.strokeColor = .mainBlueTint
            lineRenderer.lineWidth = 4
            return lineRenderer
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
}
```

**TableView didSelectRowAt Method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let placemark = self.searchResults[indexPath.row]
        
        configureActionButtonState(config: .dismissActionView)
        
        let destination = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        self.generatePolyline(toDestination: destination)
        
        self.dismissInputView { _ in
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
            
        }
    }
```

Finally, here's the whole view controller, just in case I've missed anything above. Please let me know if any further information is required to answer the question and I'll provide it.

**Entire view controller**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import MapKit

private enum ActionButtonConfiguration {
    case showMenu
    case dismissActionView
    
    init() {
        self = .showMenu
    }
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK:- Properties
    
    private let mapView = MKMapView()
    private let locationManager = LocationHandler.shared.locationManager
    private let inputActivationView = LocationInputActivationView()
    private let locationInputView = LocationInputView()
    private var searchResults = [MKPlacemark]()
    private var actionButtonConfig = ActionButtonConfiguration()
    private var route: MKRoute?
    
    private let tableView = UITableView()
    
    private var user: User? {
        didSet {
            locationInputView.user = user
        }
    }
    
    private let actionButton: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "baseline_menu_black_36dp").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapActionButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    
    // MARK:- Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkIfUserLoggedIn()
        locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(locationManager!)
        
    }
    
    // MARK:- Selectors
    
    @objc private func didTapActionButton() {
        switch actionButtonConfig {
        case .showMenu:
            print("Show menu")
        case .dismissActionView:
            removeAnnotationsAndOverlays()
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.configureActionButtonState(config: .showMenu)
                self.inputActivationView.alpha = 1
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK:- API
    
    private func fetchUserData() {
        guard let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        Service.shared.fetchUserData(uid: currentUserId) { user in
            self.user = user
        }
        
    }
    
    // N.B. Service.shared.fetchDrivers automatically gets called every time the location of the driver changes since it is observing the database via geofire (see definition of this within Service.swift)
    private func fetchDrivers() {
        guard let location = locationManager?.location else { return }
        Service.shared.fetchDrivers(location: location) { (driver) in
            guard let coordinate = driver.location?.coordinate else { return }
            let annotation = DriverAnnotation(uid: driver.uid, coordinate: coordinate)
            
            var driverIsVisible: Bool {
                return self.mapView.annotations.contains { annotation -> Bool in
                    guard let driverAnnotation = annotation as? DriverAnnotation else { return false }
                    if driverAnnotation.uid == driver.uid {
                        // Driver is already visible - update driver location whenever this function is called
                        driverAnnotation.updateAnnotationPosition(withCoordinate: coordinate)
                        return true
                    }
                    
                    // Driver is not visible
                    return false
                }
                
            }
            
            // If driver is not visible then add to map
            if !driverIsVisible {
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    
    private func checkIfUserLoggedIn() {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
            // User is not logged in
            print("DEBUG: User is not logged in")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController())
                nav.isModalInPresentation = true
                nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            // User is logged in
            configure()
        }
        
    }
    
    private func logOut() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController())
                nav.isModalInPresentation = true
                nav.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } catch {
            print("DEBUG: Error signing user out: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK:- Public Helper Functions
    
    public func configure() {
        configureUI()
        fetchUserData()
        fetchDrivers()
    }
    
    public func configureUI() {
        configureMapView()
        configureActionButton()
        configureInputActivationView()
        configureTableView()
    }
    
    // MARK:- Private Helper Functions
    
    private func configureActionButton() {
        view.addSubview(actionButton)
        actionButton.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, left: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor,
                            paddingTop: 16, paddingLeft: 16, width: 30, height: 30)
    }
    
    private func configureActionButtonState(config: ActionButtonConfiguration) {
        switch config {
        case .showMenu:
            self.actionButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "baseline_menu_black_36dp").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
            self.actionButtonConfig = .showMenu
        case .dismissActionView:
            self.actionButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "baseline_arrow_back_black_36dp-1").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
            self.actionButtonConfig = .dismissActionView
        }
    }
    
    private func configureMapView() {
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.frame = view.frame
        
        mapView.delegate = self
        
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
    }
    
    private func configureInputActivationView() {
        inputActivationView.delegate = self
        
        view.addSubview(inputActivationView)
        inputActivationView.centerX(inView: view)
        inputActivationView.anchor(top: actionButton.bottomAnchor, left: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, right: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 18, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20, height: 40)
        
        // Animate inputActivationView (fade in)
        inputActivationView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
            self.inputActivationView.alpha = 1
        }
    }
    
    private func configureLocationInputView() {
        locationInputView.delegate = self
        
        view.addSubview(locationInputView)
        locationInputView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, height: 200)
        locationInputView.alpha = 0
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.locationInputView.alpha = 1
        } completion: { _ in
            print("DEBUG: Present table view")
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.tableView.frame.origin.y = self.locationInputView.frame.height
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func configureTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.register(LocationTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: LocationTableViewCell.identifier)
        
        tableView.rowHeight = 60
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        
        let height = view.frame.height - locationInputView.frame.height
        tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height, width: view.frame.width, height: height)
    }
    
    private func dismissInputView(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.locationInputView.alpha = 0
            self.tableView.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.height
            self.locationInputView.removeFromSuperview()
        }, completion: completion)
    }
    
    private func removeAnnotationsAndOverlays() {
        mapView.annotations.forEach { annotation in
            if let anno = annotation as? MKPointAnnotation {
                mapView.removeAnnotation(anno)
            }
        }
        if mapView.overlays.count > 0 {
            mapView.removeOverlay(mapView.overlays[0])
        }
    }
    
}

// MARK:- MapView Functions

extension HomeViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    
    private func generatePolyline(toDestination destination: MKMapItem) {
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()
        request.destination = destination
        request.transportType = .automobile
        
        let directionRequest = MKDirections(request: request)
        directionRequest.calculate { (response, error) in
            guard let response = response else { return }
            self.route = response.routes[0]
            guard let polyline = self.route?.polyline else { return }
            self.mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
            
        }
    }
    
    private func searchBy(naturalLanguageQuery: String, completion: @escaping([MKPlacemark]) -> Void) {
        var results = [MKPlacemark]()
        
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.region = mapView.region
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = naturalLanguageQuery
        
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { (response, error) in
            guard let response = response else { return }
            
            response.mapItems.forEach { (item) in
                results.append(item.placemark)
            }
            completion(results)
        }
        
    }
    
    // Change driver annotation appearance to Uber arrow
    public func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if let annotation = annotation as? DriverAnnotation {
            let view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: DriverAnnotation.identifier)
            view.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chevron-sign-to-right")
            return view
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if let route = self.route {
            let polyline = route.polyline
            let lineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: polyline)
            lineRenderer.strokeColor = .mainBlueTint
            lineRenderer.lineWidth = 3
            return lineRenderer
        }
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
}

// MARK:- Location Manager Services

extension HomeViewController {
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("DEBUG: Not determined")
            locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            break
        case .denied:
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("DEBUG: Auth always")
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("DEBUG: Auth when in use")
            locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
}

// MARK:- Input Activation View Delegate Methods

extension HomeViewController: LocationInputActivationViewDelegate {
    func presentLocationInputView() {
        configureLocationInputView()
        self.inputActivationView.alpha = 0
    }
    
}

// MARK:- Input View Delegate Methods

extension HomeViewController: LocationInputViewDelegate {
    func executeSearch(query: String) {
        searchBy(naturalLanguageQuery: query) { (results) in
            print("DEBUG: Placemarks are \(results)")
            self.searchResults = results
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
    }
    
    func dismissLocationInputView() {
        dismissInputView()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.inputActivationView.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}

// MARK:- TableView Delegate and Datasource Methods

extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        2
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "test"
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return section == 0 ? 2 : searchResults.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: LocationTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! LocationTableViewCell
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cell.placemark = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let placemark = self.searchResults[indexPath.row]
        
        configureActionButtonState(config: .dismissActionView)
        
        let destination = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        self.generatePolyline(toDestination: destination)
        
        self.dismissInputView { _ in
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            self.mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output in the debug window also, not sure if it's relevant:

```
2021-01-26 19:36:40.853479+0700 Uber[17163:1579722] [Default] InfoLog PolylineOverlayFillShader: WARNING: 0:42: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
WARNING: 0:48: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
WARNING: 0:54: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
WARNING: 0:66: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
WARNING: 0:68: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
WARNING: 0:72: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
WARNING: 0:74: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
WARNING: 0:78: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
WARNING: 0:80: Overflow in implicit constant conversion, minimum range for lowp float is (-2,2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the code executed in your 'rendererFor' function?  It looks like you're adding the overlay route in 'generatePolyline' and then creating it again based on self.route

Comment: @Russell If I remove `if let route = self.route { let polyline = route.polyline }` from the 'rendererFor' function and replace `let lineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: polyline)` with `let lineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)`, the same thing happens (no overlay). Does the 'rendererFor' function not just automatically get called via the line 'self.mapView.addOverlay(polyline)'? Apologies, I'm a relative beginner so I'm not 100% sure what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simplified version of this - with a hard-coded destination, but creating the route as you do, and this works very nicely.

```
private func generatePolyline(toDestination destination: MKMapItem) {
    let request = MKDirections.Request()
    request.source = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()
    request.destination = destination
    request.transportType = .automobile
    
    let directionRequest = MKDirections(request: request)
    directionRequest.calculate { (response, error) in
        guard let response = response else { return }
        self.route = response.routes[0]
        guard let polyline = self.route?.polyline else { return }
        self.mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
        print("update map?")
    }
}
```

the only thing I have added here is the debug print statement at the end - always nice to know that something **should** be happening, but always good to know it actually has!

I called the function from a simple test button

```
@IBAction func cmdButton(_ sender: Any) {
    // for testing - Edinburgh Castle
    generatePolyline(toDestination: MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  55.9483, longitude: -3.1981), addressDictionary: nil)))
}
```

The renderer is very simple, and includes a test print as above

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let pr = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        pr.strokeColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        pr.lineWidth = 7
        print("rendererFor overlay")
        return pr
}
```

If you're seeing the debug print comments, you should be ok.  Let me know how you get on...

Comment: Thanks for your reply - it seems as though the reason that it's not working is that I'm in Cambodia, and Apple Maps doesn't seem to able show directions within Cambodia yet. After digging a little deeper I printed the error message from `directionRequest.calculate { (response, error) in` and it came up with 'Directions are not available from this location'. I then checked the Maps app and it did the same thing... Guess I'll have to resort to Google Maps if I want a line drawn then.

Comment: that's a shame.  I didn't think about directions just not being available!

Comment: I'm in a capital city so it didn't cross my mind either! Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little deeper, the reason is that I'm in Phnom Penh, Cambodia. Apple Maps doesn't have the ability to give directions in Cambodia. Guess I'll have to resort to Google Maps if I want a line drawn from one point to another then.